# Sql Server 2005 time conversion from american to indian time

Tags: sql-server-2005

Can you tell me how to convert the american time to indian time. Just give me the function that converts the american time to Indian time. The time difference is 11.5 hours

Answer (score 2):

Maybe there is more elegant solution, but as work around you can use T-SQL function [DATEADD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258267%28v=SQL.80%29.aspx) to add time difference between time zones